# Приложение qt не подключается к базе данных

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Программа должна подключаться к базе данных, либо создавать ее. Все работает хорошо при запуске в Qt Creator'е, но при запуске через exe файл ничего не происходит.

```
bool database::checkDB()
{
    QString addr;
    addr = QDir::currentPath() + QString("/database1.db");
    if (QFile(addr).exists())
        return openDB(addr);
    else
        return restoreDB(addr);
}

bool database::openDB(QString addr)
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(addr);
    return db.open();
}

void database::closeDB()
{
    db.close();
    db.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
}

bool database::createDB()
{
    QSqlQuery qry;
    if (qry.exec("CREATE TABLE Worker ( `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
                              AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,"
                              " `name` TEXT, `date` TEXT, `base_rate` REAL,"
                              " `position` TEXT, `username` TEXT, `password` 
                              TEXT,"
                              " `ch_id` INTEGER )"))
    {
        if (qry.exec("insert into Worker(name, username, password) "
                     "VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 'admin')"))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
    else
        return false;

}  

bool database::restoreDB(QString addr)
{
    if (openDB(addr))
        return createDB();
    else
        return false;
}
```

// Подключение происходит в конструкторе формы.

```
login::login(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    if (db.checkDB())
        ui->status->setText("Connected!");
    else
        ui->status->setText("Isn't connect!");
}
```

Comment: Если в папке с exe нет папки `plugins/sqldrivers` с нужным dll, то работать не будет

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если запускаете под Windows, лучше собрать приложение через windeployqt - он подтянет все зависимости в директорию с приложением. windeployqt поставляется в Qt, найдете его через поиск, если требуется - пропишите в PATH.

В случае запуска для Linux убедитесь, что динамические библиотеки, в том числе библиотеки БД коннекторов, доступны в LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Для Linux есть определенный резон ставить Qt из пакетов, если вам не требуются какие-то совсем новые возможности. Хотя через Qt Chooser все тоже прекрасно интегрируется.

Comment: А, вижу, что через exe - тогда только верхний абзац: https://evileg.com/ru/post/163/

Answer (score 0):

Если не запускается .exe файл, для запуска приложения без IDE, то в папку с этим экзешником нужно поместить недостающие dll файлы.

надо, чтоб в папке release находились недостающие dll,
а копировать их из папки C://Qt/ ... /mingw48-32/bin

подробнее здесь:
http://blog.harrix.org/article/1015